# server side programming mobile apps vs websites

Tags: java, php, web-services, rest, frameworks

I am trying to build a hybrid mobile app..but this is my first time so the below questions-

1. Is there any difference in server side scripting/programming for mobile apps vs websites.
2. Which is better MVC or webservices(RESTapi). Or is there any other better way.
3. Also for webservices which is a better choice for serving requests - php, java, node.js etc.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

If you want your app to run off-line then you'll need to have all necessary logic running client-side, which is usually implemented with an "MVC" JS framework and annoying HTML5 app cache or packaging like PhoneGap/Cordova.

Mobile phones often have high-latency 3G connections (or high-latency low-bandwidth 2G), so for best performance you'll have to have very terse API that makes as much work as possible in a single request.

If you're only using HTTP request then it doesn't matter much what you use on the server side. If you'd like to stream some data in real time, e.g. via [Server-Sent events](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/) then you'll need node or similar event-based python/ruby/java server.

If you can't/don't have to run off-line and have an existing website with reasonably clean HTML then it may be enough to add mobile-friendly CSS to it, see "Responsive design".

Comment: actually i need it to interact with the database

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd say the biggest advantage of using a website is that it will run on every platform, while an app is only for a specific platform. And the biggest advantage of the app is the availability of all the functionnalities provided by the phone (camera, geolocation, SMS etc...) which can be useful or not depending on what kind of service your are implementing.
2. The advantage of REST is that you can build both a website and an app in front of it, using json as data echange format.

Comment: Web apps can use [geolocation](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/) and [camera](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/).

Comment: no i am basically asking is there any difference in backend(server end) for a website and mobileapp. I see from your second point it should serve both right?